# get the term id from the url in views module

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I have a portfolio view; the portfolio displays all the nodes of the *portfolio* content type in a grid and, basing on the selected term of the tags above, shows the associated content in images and titles and some description.
I'm adding the view block of the portfolio in the Tags page (taxonomy-term.tpl.php).

How can I get the term from the URL and make the view show only the child terms of that term?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can: In your block-view's admin page, look at the Advanced section; click to add a new "Content: Has taxonomy term ID" contextual argument. From the section "When the filter value is NOT in the URL," choose "Provide default value "; then, select "Taxonomy term ID from URL."

This should do the trick.